# Javascript Form Not Returning Values

Tags: javascript

It looks good, but it's not returning any values.
Any ideas?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.out {
    height: 22px;
    width: 100px;
    border:solid 1px;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
form input {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form>Number 1
    <input type="text" id="firstNumber">Number 2
    <input type="text" id="secondNumber">Number 3
    <input type="text" id="thirdNumber">
    <input type="button" value="Add Total" onclick="addIt()">
    <div class="out" id="Total"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Multiply Total" onclick="multiply()">
    <div class="out" id="multiplyresult"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Ave Total" onclick="averesult()">
    <div class="out" id="averesult"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var result = getId('Total'),
    multiplyresult = getId('multiplyresult'),
    n1, n2, n3;

function getValues() {
    n1 = getId('firstNumber').value, n2 = getId('secondNumber').value, n3 = getId('thirdNumber').value;
}
console.log((n1) * (n2) * (n3));
window.addIt = function() {
    getValues();
    result.innerText = (+n1) + (+n2) + (+n3);
};
window.multiply = function() {
    getValues();
    multiplyresult.innerText = (n1) * (n2) * (n3);
};
window.average = function() {
    getValues();
    averesult.innerText = (n1) + (n2) + (n3) / 3;
};

function getId(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
</script>
```

I also was trying to figure out how to return and average value of the three numbers.
But as I am a total novice, I do not know how to do this.
The add and multiply functions are now working, but not the average.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried adding the script _after_ the html? or using [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) ?

Comment: You were trying to access to html elements (nodes) that weren't available when the script was evaluated. Try adding `console.log(getId('multiplyresult'))` after and before the div, and see what the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) outputs.

Comment: Move the script after form, as  result = getId('Total') should after <div class="out" id="Total"> http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/qA3AE/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average has to be calculated like so:

```
window.average = function() {
    getValues();
    averesult.innerText = ((n1) + (n2) + (n3)) / 3; //Note brackets around n1->n3
};
```

And your call to `averesult()` needs to be changed to `average()`

Comment: Your onclick needs to call `average()` not `averesult()`

Comment: @user3109332 If this answer has helped you, you can aid future people with similar problems by accepting/upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you ran the script as soon as the page loaded, before all the elements had loaded. Because of that, you were trying to access elements that did not exist yet, and would not exist until the page had finished loading. This can be solved in one of two ways. The first way is wrapping it in a `window.onload`, and the second way is just moving the `<script></script>` tags to the end of the `<body>`